# setting background image in mvc layout page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to set the background image in the MVC layout page. I have created the css. How do I set it in the layout. Not sure where to put it.

Below is my css file

**app.css**

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-top: none;
    background-image: url('../Images/iNeed__waterfall_BG.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
      background-color:red;
}



.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:white;
}

.navbar-header img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-top:15px;
}

nav navbar-nav navbar-right{
    text-align:center;
}

.hideli {
    padding-right: 200px;
}
```

Below is the layout page of my project.

**Layout Page**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/angular.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jszip.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>

</head>
<body >

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="~/Images/NGSR-logo.jpg" /> </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Admin</p></a></li>


                        <li class="dropdown hideli">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <select>
                                    <option><a href="#">ALL</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">DE</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">GB</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">FR</a></option>
                                </select>
                                <p>Country</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

    </header>

    <div>

        @*<img src="~/Images/iNeed__waterfall_BG.jpg" />*@
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }
  }
```

**index.html**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it in the right place, but you need to wrap your filepath in quotes and use the 'background' property.

background: url('../Images/iNeed__waterfall_BG.jpg');

Comment: Is that enough just declaring the property in the css. Where to I apply the background property in layout

Comment: You might need to change the '~' to '..'.  I test in my project and it worked with the '..' but not the '~'.  Not sure why, however.

Comment: It still dosent work. The link to the image is correct. The name of the image spelt is correct. I have enclosed it in double quotes. I have checked the developer tools and there is no error in the console window. What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include your Main.css into your HTML.

Add the following to your `HTML` `<head>` section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Main.css does not exist. The implementation is in app.css. Where to I apply the background property

Comment: Is the CSS above is in app.css?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to apply it as a class property in layout

Comment: No. your CSS looks good. As long it's linked correct to your HTML, the style should apply. Make sure that the image is spelled correctly and is in the right path

Comment: It still dosent work. The link to the image is correct. The name of the image spelt is correct. I have enclosed it in double quotes. I have checked the developer tools and there is no error in the console window. What am I missing

Comment: Can you share your full code? Also, what's the name of the HTML file?

Comment: I have shared the entire code. so please bear in mind that it is asp.mvc application. So when routing kicks off, the home controller is called and layout and index page is rendered

Comment: Which party isn't working, does any of the styles in the app.css apply? Or the entire CSS file is being ignored

Comment: The rest of the css is applying but what is not applying is the body {}. The navbar classes, hideli are applying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136848/discussion-between-tom-and-moses-davidowitz).

Comment: Non of the body styles? Background color isn't red?

Comment: I just cleared the cache and checked again.
It does apply. but the image is not rendering completely

Comment: If i directly set the image tag in the layout , it renders completely

Comment: It only renders completly when I set the image tag about the renderbody() call

Answer (score 0):

I would place it here:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />  /* <-- HERE */
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Main.css does not exist. The implementation is in app.css. Where to I apply the background property